# How do I fetch data from a Angular JS application using a company's own API?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on the Front End Development for a company with a CRUD application using Angular JS. They want me to build out the views and grab the data using their API. (I've never done this)

He's telling me the syntax to grab the data would be something like this(this is just an example):

```
var getItems = function () {
        return $http
            .get('/api/1/items/available')
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.items = data.items;
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                messageCenterService.add('danger', 'Unable to get the available Tickets and Passes.');
            });
    };
```

Then he said:

```
when you return the $http function, you can use it like:
getItems().then(... callback success, callback error...)
or move success() also
getItems().success(...).then(...)
```

Can someone help me understand what's going on here or guide me to a good tutorial with API's and Angular? I looked all over the web to find this and can't find anything that resembles this.

Comment: have you readed the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) documnetation?

Comment: I will review it once more, but I'm unsure how the api is being pulled in and was hoping there was a tutorial on explaining this step by step.

Answer (score 1):

From the doc:

"
The $http service is a function which takes a single argument — a configuration object — that is used to generate an HTTP request and returns a promise with two $http specific methods: success and error.
...
Since the returned value of calling the $http function is a promise, you can also use the then method to register callbacks, and these callbacks will receive a single argument – an object representing the response.
"

$http.get is a shortcut method to perform GET request.

when you call `$http.get('/api/1/items/available')` you are making a GET request to '/api/1/items/available'.
As the request is asynchronous, you have to define a callback function to manipulate the result, and callbacks functions are registered by 'success' and 'then' methods of promise returned by $http call.
The 'error' method is used to register error callbacks.

If you are working with a REST api, you can use the [Resource angular module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

Comment: This is really confusing to me, where would you recommend I go to learn about this and follow some tutorials?

Comment: Do you know something about Ajax?

Comment: I know that ajax works by communicating with the server without refreshing the page, but I have a difficult time seeing the connection syntactically with Angular.

Comment: the $http module do the same as Ajax do, but inside the angular context. If you understand Ajax, you'r gonna understand $http module. think in $http as a shortcut of an Ajax resquest. Try to study about Ajax made by jQuery.